# Как сделать копирование файла с CD-DVD с "перескоком"?

Tags: delphi

Так было сделано в программе NS-Copy. Там когда встречается ошибочный сектор, то совершается т.н. "перескок" - целый блок секторов пропускается, копирование начинается в обратном направлении до встречи с концом блока битых секторов.
Так чтение файлов идет гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на АПИшные FileOpen, FileSeek, FileRead, FileClose. 
Для FileRead указываете наибольший размер буфера, если при чтении возникла ошибка, пробуете уменьшить размер буфера и прочитать еще раз, повторять до уменьшения буфера вплоть до одного байта, пока не прочитается. Ну в общем делаете удобную вам логику.